# What is 'TextFile' and where it is uses in WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

i want to know about the use of 'TextFile' item in wpf project-
1)I am Create a project in VS2010 .
2)write click on project(Or click on 'Project Tab in MenuBar')-->select 'Add New Item'-->          in open dialog box,appear 'TextFile' option. see in picture.-

[image]

Comment: You can add any file you like to a project.

Answer (score 7):

That's just a text file. It does nothing.

As with any other file, you are free to include it in your project as a resource, and perhaps load it at runtime via `GetResourceStream()` or something.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on the previous answer, text files can be very useful in a number of ways, especially if you have multiple people working on a project.  Adding a todo list or instructions to other developers in the project tree itself makes them more obvious.

It also helps to keep them up-to-date when using code revision control.

(Would have commented but not enough reputation... the previous answer sums it up)

Answer (score 0):

I add 'TextFile' in project ,now problem is ,How to access it(Or Open it) on Button click Event.

[image]

Comment: Right click and set it as a resource to copy into the output. It will then be available to your program in the application's working directory.